# how to plot matrix element of a matrix valued function as a function of a parameter

Tags: python, matplotlib, matrix, dtype

I have defined a matrix-valued function. It is a 2x2 matrix whose each element is dependent on some parameters. Out of all the parameters ,I vary one, fixing the others and want to plot the variation of matrix elements as a function of the varied parameter. However, when I execute it, it shows me some error related to data type.

Here is my code:
First I define some element

```
def S11(x,ce):
    return np.exp(1j*x*ce)+x/ce

def S12(x,ce,cx,rh,l):
    return np.exp(1j*x*ce)-x/ce
```

Then I define matrix as:

```
def Srl(x,ce):
    return np.array([[S12(x,ce), S11(x,ce)], [S11(x,ce), S12(x,ce)]])
```

Then I define a function whose input is a matrix itself:

```
def Tm(S) :
    return 1/S[0,1]*np.array([[-S[0,0], 1], [S[0,1]*S[1, 0]-S[0, 0]*S[1,1], S[1,1]]])
```

Let's say, I take x as a variable and fix ce

```
x= np.linspace(-1,1,101)
```

If I plot `Tm(Srl(x,ce))[0,0]` vs x it shows an error:

> operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (101,) (2,2)

Comment: Please format your code as a code block and include the entire error message.